# Have Edge Ignore "There was an error parsing the JSON document. The document may not be well-formed."

Tags: json, microsoft-edge

I am using the Edge browser to view an internal web page inside my company.  Edge will not render the page and instead displays the following:

`There was an error parsing the JSON document. The document may not be well-formed.`

However, I can open the page in Chrome and it ignores the JSON parsing error.  Is there anyway to have Edge ignore the JSON parsing error and still render the web page?

Comment: Does it work in Edge with InPrivate window? I don't find the way to let Edge ignore the JSON parsing error, I think you'd better contact the website to fix the JSON format issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I had a JSON extension installed in Edge.   Removed it and everything returned to normal.